# Se puede cambiar el valor de un campo al guardar esos datos en otra tabla?

Tags: php, mysql

No supe como redactar bien la pregunta pero la cosa es asi. En la tabla `mantenimiento` tengo un campo llamado `estado`. Este campo automáticamente se guarda como pendiente y en la segunda tabla llamada `orden` se jalan los datos de `matenimiento` por el id.

Lo que quisiera es que al jalar dichos datos a `orden` y guardarlos, que el `estado` de `mantenimiento` cambie a `listo`

**Mantenimiento**

```
Id_mante    Equipo      Estado
```

**Orden**

```
Id_orden     Id_mante   Valor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la tabla `ORDEN` debes programar un  trigger `After INSERT` en donde ejecutes algo así como

```
Update MANTENIMIENTO set ESTADO = "listo" where MANTENIMIENTO_id = new.MANTENIMIENTO_ID.

CREATE TRIGGER BI_ORDEN AFTER INSERT ON ORDEN ...
```